# plot multiple regression lines on same plot

Tags: r

This plots a line for the price and year. How do I plot another line for the TotalSold and Year in the same plot?

```
library(plyr)
library(RODBC, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
conn = odbcConnect("Test")
q <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT [Year]
      ,[Price]
      ,[TotalSold]
  FROM [dbo].[wine]")

library(ggplot2)

#create plot to visualize fitted linear regression model
ggplot(q,aes(Year, Price)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

It only plots 2 lines. It looks like the 1st 2. Age and Weight are not plotted.

```
library(plyr)
library(RODBC, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
conn = odbcConnect("Test1")
q <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT [Year]
      ,[Price]
      ,[TotalSold]
      ,[Age]
      ,[Weight]
  FROM [dbo].[wine]")

library(ggplot2)

#create plot to visualize fitted linear regression model
ggplot(q, aes(Year, Price)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Price")) +  # Points for Price
  geom_smooth(aes(color = "Price"), method = 'lm') +  # Regression line
  geom_line(aes(y = TotalSold))
  geom_line(aes(y = Age))
  geom_line(aes(y = Weight))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add another line by adding it as a new layer like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(q, aes(Year, Price)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Price")) +  # Points for Price
  geom_smooth(aes(color = "Price"), method = 'lm') +  # Regression line
  geom_line(aes(y = TotalSold))
```

Following your edit, you are almost there with the plotting. but there is a little syntax problem. to add new layers in ggplot2, you need to include the `+` sign at the end of each layer, except the last layer, like this:

```
ggplot(q, aes(Year, Price)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "Price")) +  # Points for Price
  geom_smooth(aes(color = "Price"), method = 'lm') +  # Regression line
  geom_line(aes(y = TotalSold)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Age)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Weight))
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Can you add unlimited number of lines for additional columns? How?

Comment: hello Shiela, yes. it is possible to add as many lines or points for additional columns as you want. in your case, since you have already made the ggplot() call, all you need to do is add the line as a layer with this syntax: geom_line(aes(y = additional_column)) there is also a possibility to add other aesthetics like color, line width, etc. hope this answered your question

Comment: Hi I updated the question to see the code. It only plots 2 lines. The other 2 lines are not plotted.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by querying R data into Power BI. Then I used the Power Bi visuals to plot the data instead of using R to plot the lines.